# How to change value of specific inputs in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

How can I change the value of input where value `!= "100"` ?

```
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="100" />
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="200" />
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="300" />
```

I tried to use

```
$('.quantity').each(function(){
...
});
```

But the loop includes all values.

Comment: What did you do _inside_ the loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.quantity').each(function(){
     var val = $(this).val();
     if(val!= 100){
       // do the code for new value
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` to access, compare and change the input value in loop.

```
$('.quantity').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != 100) {
        $(this).val("999");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```js
$("input[value!=100].quantity").each(function(){
    $(this).val(999);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="100" />
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="200" />
<input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="300" />
```